# Title attribute value stay the same after setting it once

Tags: jquery

I have a div:

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

And there's a javascript function that brings up a JQueryUI dialog:

```
ui_info(title,txt)
{
     $('#dialog').attr('title', title).text(txt).dialog({
    width: 500,
    buttons:
[{
    text: 'OK',
    click: function ()
    {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
}
],
});
return false;
}
```

My problem is if I call this method once I get title and the text right. But if I call it again the text changes , however the title for the dialog remains the same. So for instance, if I call this function like this:

```
ui_info('First title','This is the first text');
```

I get the title 'This is title 1' and the text 'This is the first text'. And then if I call it again like this:

```
ui_info('Next title','The text is different now');
```

For text I'll get 'The text is different now', which is what I want, but for the title I still get 'First title', whereas I'm expecting 'Next title'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).dialog('destroy');` instead of `$(this).dialog('close');`

Demo of your version: http://jsfiddle.net/wCWTE/1/

Demo of corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/wCWTE/

If you still want to use the `close` method you can use the `open` event and setting the title using the option given by default by the dialog settings, so you will have:

```
function ui_info(title,txt)
{
  $('#dialog').text(txt).dialog({
    width: 500,
    buttons:
    [{
       text: 'OK',
       click: function ()
       {
          $(this).dialog('close');
       }
    }],
    open:function() {
        $(this).dialog('option','title',title)
    }
  });
}
```

Please see this new demo http://jsfiddle.net/wCWTE/2/

Comment: Ok, I see. With destroy it works. But could you tell me the mechanism of this? Why does it not work with close?

Comment: `destroy` remove the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state. `close` will just close the dialog letting the settings as they are. When you open again the dialog after you closing it with the close method I think that the title is not reinitialize

Comment: What I can't understand is why it removes the text but not the title.

Comment: Please see the modification in my answer